# Matrix convolutional multiplication with CMSIS-DSP

Tags: arm, fft, matrix-multiplication, convolution, cmsis

Can the library CMSIS-DSP do matrix convolutional multiplication?
When I looking at the [documentation](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__Conv.html#ga2e977f76e873bd47c6c41c7d940fdf7e) of the library I can see that it only supports regular convolutional vector multiplication.

**Question:**

Is there any way to do matrix convolutional multiplication in ARM systems for large kernels by using a proper library that take optimized benefits of the hardware?

Comment: The first question you should ask is what is the precision you need to keep the calculations within range (no over/underflow).  You will get a speed up with SIMD if you use fixed point.  Some Cortex-M only have single precision floats.  Start with a double algorithm and input bounds.  See if conversion to single precision matters.  If performance is still needed then you need to see what fixed point formats can work.  Having convolution values of 'zero' or 'one' is very helpful.  This depends on whether the convolution is fixed or not.  If the CPU has no SIMD, fixed point may not be a benefit.

Comment: @artlessnoise in this case, i only use single precision e.g floats. I care more about speed rather than precision. I have a plain C algorithm för convolution 1D and 2D in plain. But I don't know if CMSIS-DSP can offer something better.

Comment: You don't care if the answer is correct?  You could just run anything.  `return 0.0f;`  I think you mean you are confident that single precision float will be sufficient.  You should check by implementing double and comparing to just float.  You can also look at float16, if your CPU supports it.  The other question I asked is what particular CPU you have (If the CPU has no...).  So, you can only work with what hardware is available.  Btw, look at the [CMSIS api and the source](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS-DSP/tree/main/Source/FilteringFunctions), otherwise, this is little effort.

Comment: Also, you only care about speed?  But fixed point is often faster (SIMD); however, you need a CPU that supports it, you need to understand it and using the minimum precision needed will almost always be the fastest.  So your statements are inconsistent.  Compare speeds with the 1D convolution on your CPU.  It is not the algorithm you want, but it is a quick way to show the speed up.  Did you do this?